Movie in which student asked to have sex with balloons
This was a comedy, late 90s or early 2000s, set in a high school (I think).
A senior student wants to teach students about safe sex, but told she cannot talk about condoms.
So she takes condoms, blows them up as balloon animals, and starts giving them free to the students. And she says something like:

Have sex with this. No, I mean it. Have sex with it.

... in a slightly creepy voice.
She gets caught, obviously, and asked to stop.

I don't think it was a movie. I'm fairly convinced you saw the Popular episode Tonight's the Night (season 1, episode 8). In it, activist Lily decides to hand out condoms in her school disguised as balloon animals, much to Ms. Glass's annoyance. And it leads to this dialogue with a student:

Lily: Have sex with it.
May Tuna: It's a poodle.
Lily: Yes, have sex with it.

It aired in late 1999. Lily Esposito was played by Tamara Mello; Maybe a picture will jog your memory:

